# Access to GMail mailbox content with google-api

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-api-java-client

Is there a way to access a Gmail Mailbox using the google-api? I'm trying to do this from command line using Java FWIW.

I already have code in place that achieves this via IMAP so that is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can access GMAIL IMAPS and SMTP using XOAUTH authentication, see here :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

It is not really the google-api-java-client, it is plain IMAP/SMTP but authentication is OAUTH2.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm already aware of IMAP and also POP3 availability but I was getting constant suggestions from the Gmail team to use the "Google API". So this question is more of a reality check to make sure I'm not missing sth obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the Google API once again and considering this question did not get an answer in the past 6 days, I guess it is safe to say there is no other way aside from IMAP/S.

NOTE:

This question was initiated because I was told by numerous people that a certain Google API was available and preferable for this purpose. It seems they were all informed by the same person who was not able to show me his source of information and agreed that according to the documentation IMAP indeed is the only API available as of now.